# Retrieve Date type as String from Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, date, serialization, deserialization

Data is mongodb is saved as below in Item collection.

```
{name:item1, addedDate: 2021-03-04}
```

addedDate is saved as Date type. And there are 1000 of such records in collection.

I am retrieving the record as below in java :

```
List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

@Autowired
MongoCollection<Item> itemCollection; 
  itemCollection.find().into(itemList);
```

Item pojo is as below:

```
public class Item{
public String addedDate;

//Getters setters
}
```

It is not able to fetch and parse the record because addedDate is of type String. When I change it to Date type it works. I have kept it as string in pojo because in response I have to return it as string.

How can I achieve this? Please advise.

Comment: Keeping your date as a string because of the output format required, polluting your model with interface considerations, that’s bad. It’s better to format to a string only when you return a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
public class Item {
    private LocalDate addedDate;

    //public getters and setters
}
```

You can learn more about it from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: It worked with LocalDate. Thanks for your answer.